# The second line of "God's Grandeur"

Tags: meaning, poetry, gerard-manley-hopkins

The second line of Gerard Manley Hopkins's sonnet [God's Grandeur](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44395/gods-grandeur) is:

> It will flame out, like shining from shook foil.

What I found on the Internet regarding the analysis of this line was rather complicated. I have to present this poem in front of my classroom and I am still just a high school student. Could anyone give me the easiest explanation , something that everyone will be able to understand please?

Answer (score 6):

When you take a sheet of metal foil and shake it vigorously, the metal sparkles as the light catches it. Here is an example of [gold foil being shaken](https://images.app.goo.gl/cCVVDiVXLLYSLhAU8). The left edge of the foil in particular is reminiscent of flames:

[image]

As you can see, the light glitters and shines off the foil in an active way. That's what Hopkins means: God's grandeur is actively reflected in the world, as light is actively reflected when foil is shaken.