# The first line of "God's Grandeur"

Tags: meaning, poetry, gerard-manley-hopkins

The first line of Gerard Manley Hopkins's sonnet ["God's Grandeur"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44395/gods-grandeur) is:

> The world is charged with the grandeur of God.

What I found on the Internet regarding the analysis of this line was rather complicated. I have to give a presentation about this poem in front of my classroom and I am still just a high school student. Please explain this line in an easily-understandable way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The second line of "God's Grandeur"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/16905/the-second-line-of-gods-grandeur)

Comment: Are both this question and the linked questions yours from separate accounts? You may want to register and link them. Also while our community is happy to help phrasing something as a "homework" question can be hit or miss especially when asking about the same work multiple times in the same way.

Comment: yes,its from my separate accounts

Comment: It's the same answer as to your previous question: the world is actively full of God's glory. The first line states this literally, the second provides a metaphor for it. Why is this a separate question?